# How to return component inside a route (Includes boolean method, map and more) using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm still learning about the using of routers, I'm trying to put a `component` inside a `path` and return it
but I just complicated things.

Those are the `routes`:

```
<Route exact path='/' component={()=>{return <Addroom/>}}/>
<Route exact path='/room' component={()=>{return <Room/>}}/>
```

Those are the the `components` that I want to return inside the `routes`:

```
  {this.state.roomsList.map((element, key) => {
          return (
            <Room
              id={key + 1}
              key={key}
              r={element.room}
              rt={element.roomType}
              ct={element.colorType}
              sr={element.boxColor}
            />
          );
        })}

        {this.state.isActive ? (
          <Addroom add={this.create} />
        ) : (
          <button style={{backgroundColor: "aquamarine", height: "20px", width: "60px", borderRadius: "5px", border: "2px"}} onClick={this.handleShow}>Create</button>
        )}
```

And this is my completely incorrect desperate attempt:

```
<Route exact path='/' component={this.state.isActive ?()=>{return (<Addroom add={this.create}/>}}
) : ( <button style={{backgroundColor: "aquamarine", height: "20px", width: "60px", borderRadius: "5px", border: "2px"}}
onClick={this.handleShow}>Create</button> )}

<Route exact path='/room' component={this.state.roomsList.map((element, key)=>
{return (<Room id={key + 1} key={key} r={element.room} rt={element.roomType} ct={element.colorType} sr={element.boxColor} />);})}
```

This is awful syntax but I don't find any examples of combining all of these in returning a `component` within a `path`..
Thank you helpers!

Comment: Can't you just prepare your components somewhere outside and then just pass them to Router?

Comment: you're right, but when it comes to a few other things includes in the return (like map function or boolean conditions) the syntax comes out wrong and I can't really rearrange or sort it out (what comes after what, parentheses..)